# plt.subplots sharex, sharey, no longer working after I set projection

Tags: matplotlib, figure, astropy

```
fig, ax=plt.subplots(6, 4,figsize=(14, 14), sharex=True, sharey=True, subplot_kw=dict(projection=fwcs[:,1,1]), gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.5, 'wspace': 0.3})
```

This is how I'm creating my axes to plot 24 plots along different line of sights in my data. See that I have sharex=True and sharey=True in there. However, this is what my figure looks like:

not working, axes not shared:
[image: not working, axes not shared]

However, if I remove the bit `subplot_kw=dict(projection=fwcs[:,1,1])`
then sharex and sharey behave as expected:

[image: working, but axes are now incorrect]

Why is the addition of the bit setting the projection correct stopping the sharex and sharey?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you clarify what `fwcs` means in the argument?

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! fwcs is the World Co-ordinate System projection that the data has been mapped to. Its dimensions are Faraday Depth, Galactic Longitude, Galactic Latitude. fwcs[:,1,1] means I am taking a "slice" of this co-ordinate system and the data to show the Faraday Depth spectra at each point in the sky.